# MVC oAuth Login - How to determine which social account they used to login

Tags: facebook, twitter, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have implemented Facebook and Twitter logins on my MVC5 site and all is working well.

What I would like to do seems quote simple but I am not sure how to do it.

I can get the username of the logged in user with:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

However I would like to know if that user logged in using Facebook or Twitter and the ProviderKey from the relevant social network.

Hopefully this is easy to do

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the external login information using below method.

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

In your action:

```
var getExternalLoginInfor = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey - thanks for your feedback.  This gives me a full list of all logins the user has registered. However, is there a way for me to tell which one they currently logged in with?

Comment: I am not sure about easy way to getting that details, someone will help you. But, if it is social login, you could add provider name into a claim and use it during the context and compare it with getExternalLoginInfor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383955/how-to-add-claims-in-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from extension method `GetExternalLoginInfo` of `AuthenticationManager`.

```
var loginInfo = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
if (loginInfo != null)
{
     var externalProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
}
```

Edit:
In your `ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager` class override method `SignInAsync`

There you can externalLoginInfo and add it as a claim

```
public override async Task SignInAsync(User user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser)
{
    var userIdentity = await CreateUserIdentityAsync(user); 

    //
    var logininfo = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("ExternalLoginProvider", logininfo.Login.LoginProvider));
    //

    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);
    if (rememberBrowser)
    {
         var rememberBrowserIdentity = AuthenticationManager.CreateTwoFactorRememberBrowserIdentity(ConvertIdToString(user.Id));
         AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, userIdentity, rememberBrowserIdentity);
    }
    else
    {
         AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, userIdentity);
    }
}
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var loginProvide = identity.FindFirst("ExternalLoginProvider").Value;
```

Comment: This appears to only work during the login process.  If I call it later then loginInfo.Login is null.