# How to add temporary information to the ASP.Net Identity (cookie)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

we are using ASP.Net MVC with the Asp.Net Identity.

We have around 100 user informations we save in the database with the identity model.

What I want is to save temporary information the identity. The Information is HOW the user is logged in right now (SMS code, password, email code etc.etc. we have a bunch of types to log in).
So that is not a database information, it is a simple temporary information as long as the auth cookie exists.

How to add this?

Comment: Use the claims system.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20400918/2056448

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a new cookie that has that information.  Something like this:

```
Response.Cookies["AdditionalInfo"]["LoginMethod"] = "SMS";
```

You can find more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx).

Be very careful how you use the information that is in there.  A malicious user could modify the values in there to be whatever they want - so if you are using cookie values for security purposes you will get hacked.

You could also look at storing that info in the view state or the session state.

Comment: That is susceptible to change by the end user, though.

Comment: Yes it is.  That isn't necessarily a deal breaker depending on how the cookie is being used.