# Save Claims value for logged user in MVC 5 app

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I need to save New Claims value to my SQL Database `[AspNetUserClaims]` table which I suppose can be done like this (please correct if I am wrong as I'm new to MVC).

The User logs in using `OAuth` from Facebook. Once logged in, he fills in some form that collects user data as well as some uploads etc using a wizard type setup. Once the multi step wizard is completed in the `View`, at the controller after `POST` these fields are saved to the database. I need to save some of the fields data to the `[AspNetUserClaims]` table which I suppose is possible in this way:

```
//Post Fields
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var Post = new PostModel();
Post.PostTitle = model.Post.PostTitle;
Post.PostBrief = model.Post.PostBrief;
db.PostModel.Add(Post);
db.SaveChanges();


// User Claims Data
var claims = new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();
claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FullName", model.UserClaims.FullName));
claims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Email", model.UserClaims.Email));
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity i = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity;
i.AddClaims(claims);

//How to make the changes to User Claims, save to the database?
```

Comment: You're calling db.SaveChanges() before adding the claims?

Comment: No, that actually below the claims part (I've done that using a Transaction) but, does that make any difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add claims in ASP.NET Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383955/how-to-add-claims-in-asp-net-identity)

Comment: @kloarubeek, Not a duplicate(tried that before posting the question), or you can say not working for me atleast.

Comment: That questions perfectly explains how to add claims. You already add claims, I think if you sign in (as explained in that question), the claims are added to the database and the cookie.