# asp.net identity: after authentication, add custom user claims to a token provided by AAD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

After a webapp is successfully authenticated by Azure Active Directory, I need to add custom claims to the token.

Essentially I want to do this in one of my controllers:

```
if (ExistsUserInDb(User.Identity.Name))
{
   User.Identity.AddClaim("superUser", "true");
}
```

So that I can keep on reusing the same token when that user does some superPrivilege action on other controllers.

Is this possible?

I've tried these links but they didn't work for me:
[How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)
[How to add claims in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383955/how-to-add-claims-in-asp-net-identity)

Answer (score 2):

> asp.net identity: after authentication, add custom user claims to a token provided by AAD

Based on my understanding, your MVC application is configured to use ASP.NET Identity for user authentication and you also use the 
[Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/) package for supporting AAD JWT bearer token authentication as follows:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = "{AAD-client-ID}"
        },
        Tenant = "{tenantID}"
    });
```

At this point, the above middle-ware would decode the token and create a `ClaimsIdentity` for wrapping the claims from the incoming JWT token. Per my understanding, you could not modify the incoming token under your controller, but you could handle this under the middle-ware settings as follows:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience = "{AAD-client-ID}"
        },
        Tenant = "{tenantID}",
        Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = (context) =>
            {   
                //check context.Ticket.Identity.Name
                //add your additional claims here
                context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("test02", "test02"));
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Moreover, I would use [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) middleware to use OpenIdConnect for AAD authentication as follows:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = async (x) =>
            {
                var identity = x.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                //check the name, add additional claims 
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("test", "test"));

                await Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Or you could try to add the claims in your controller as follows:

```
var identity= User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("test1", "test1"));
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```

Details, you could follow [Integrate Azure AD into a web application using OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/).